# Don't allow text input in one field when another field has content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Essentially I want a form with 2 text fields, but I only want my user to fill out one. Thus, if one is filled, the other is "whited out" so to speak and cannot be filled out. If they want to fill out the whited out field, they must erase the field that has text in it (and then both fields are now open for writing).

How can I create this functionality? CSS, Javascript, or Jquery solutions, please.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" id="field1"> <!-- if there's text in this field, don't allow the field below to be filled out-->
<input type="text" id="field2"> <!-- and vice versa with this one-->
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Solutions... well what have you tried? You need to try something first before others can help you.

Comment: I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: I agree. Did you really try to figure it out yourself? Maybe use events?

Comment: Well I'm not sure how to begin to figure it out, considering I'm sort of a noob at jquery & javascript. Is there a term for a field that is "whited out"? I tried searching for this and didn't see anything.

Comment: Well I could recommend you start by looking at event handlers for input elements. Get used to using those and then make some an attempt of your own. If you still have problems then return here and I'm sure someone will be happy to help you since people can see you have researched and tried rather than just posting here and expecting others to do it for you. Take a look at this http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Comment: By "whited out" I assume you mean "disabled"...as @NewToJS mentioned, do a little homework and take a stab at it. Post your code if you have trouble and we can assist from there.

Comment: I guess disabled, but I also meant having a lowered opacity. Thanks for the input guys, I will take that into consideration for the next time I post a question. I'm still new to Javascript and Jquery so I wasn't sure where to get started and a Google search didn't provide me great results. I appreciate your help though.

Answer (score 0):

You won't learn much by asking questions like this without doing research first, but here's a freebie using jQuery since it's simple.

```js
$('input').on('keydown', function() {
  if ( $(this).attr('id') == 'field1' && $('#field2').val() ||
       $(this).attr('id') == 'field2' && $('#field1').val() ) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="field1">
  <!-- if there's text in this field, don't allow the field below to be filled out-->
  <input type="text" id="field2">
  <!-- and vice versa with this one-->
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Hey thanks man. How would I also change the opacity of the input that needs to be disabled?

Comment: *"You won't learn much by asking questions like this"* So wouldn't it be a good idea to explain the source code so that Kevinkt can understand the source code? This is why I don't answer questions like this because to make it a good answer you have to explain almost every line... in detail just to make a worthy/good answer.